# Is there a webpack dependency object that takes content instead of filepath? (developing plugin)

Tags: webpack

A webpack plugin can transform `require("something")` into something like `__webpack_require__(165)` using `CommonJsRequireDependency` as in [lib/dependencies/CommonJsRequireDependencyParserPlugin.js#L74-L82](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/aa5e21f2bd6f8c0f3fb33e560ce3233e5e0cc966/lib/dependencies/CommonJsRequireDependencyParserPlugin.js#L74-L82). `CommonJsRequireDependency` takes `request` (a filepath) and a `range`.

Is there any dependency object that instead of passing the filepath, takes the file content itself? (I want to generate the contents dynamically).

PS: I had this question while implementing a plugin that injects a dependency dynamically generated on the fly.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing, where I want to inject content during compilation.  I've tried interrupting the process with loader, but that seems wrong, and I end up having to run webpack from the loader.  You can see it here,  https://github.com/adjavaherian/sass-lifter-loader but any progress on your problem?  How do you inject content?

Comment: Currently, I'm creating a temporary file with the dynamic content and passing its filepath. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can make the context of the require() statement itself dynamic beyond the dynamic context stuff included in webpack (http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)

However, I ran into a similar problem while dealing with creating config json based off of environment variables. I ended up creating a custom loader that would create the dynamic content. It ended up looking something like this:

```
var config = require('config!.)
```

and then my custom loader was something like:

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    this.cacheable();
    var callback = this.async();

    myLib.getConfig()
        .then(function(config) {
            callback(null, config)
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far, although I'm still pursing a way to do this via a plugin.